# How can I access Transport for London from my device?

Tags: applications

How can I use TFL information on my device?  Is there an application or other good way of accessing TFL?

For those who don't know, TFL == Transport for London, a webpage of London public transport when you can find what is the best way of getting from point A to B at a given time.

Comment: Did you search in the Market for "TFL"?

Comment: @Al Everett: Yes. I used even one high ranked free application but it failed to work.

Comment: I'm developing Pubtran London, if you have any feedback let me know.

Comment: @fhucho: It looks very good. Thanks. Showing on map/choosing destination on map would be nice (yes, I know that it's probably not your day job and well... probably it is your hobby given the lack of pay version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the highest rated app I found Appbrain: http://www.appbrain.com/app/pubtran-london/cz.fhejl.pubtran.london

Here's the search I used: http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=tfl&sort=highest-rated

Answer (score 0):

The one that used to be called transport for london is now called london underground and now has pay and ad supported versions.

http://www.appbrain.com/app/london-underground-free/com.visualit.tubeLondonCity

Answer (score 0):

Transport for London has an out of date Security Certificate for Android. Until it is updated, you will not be able to access the site.